# Use @pattern from spring if other field is not empty

Tags: java, spring, forms, annotations

I have a form where there is to fields which are adress and apartment number.
lets suppose that anyone who enters an adress has an apartment number (it will make the question easier). if the adress field is not null, i want to use @pattern to make sur the field apartment is properly filled. How can I make the annotation show the error message only if the first field is not null.

In other words, can i and how can i use the @pattern annotation on a condition.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly the only way to make a "conditional" validation annotation that can reference multiple fields is to roll a custom one, like [so](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator). In the implementation class you have access to the full object and you can check/read any field you wish.